# Text to text how I fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I put text in `<p>` tags and the script is supposed to cycle through the `<p>`s, fading out the old text and fading in the new. My problem is that all the `<p>`s are shown at once which results in this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>World</p>
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <p>Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{ position:relative; }
#container p{ position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#container p:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function () {
    $('#container p:first-child').fadeOut('slow')
        .next('p').fadeIn('slow')
        .end().appendTo('#container');
}, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCgzx/)

Comment: 1. not understandable 2. no example code (jsfiddle or something at least)

Comment: ...  very warm welcome.

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear what you're trying to achieve and post some code.. Thanks

Comment: Ok that's an understatement ... please try the best you can to be more precise. And use punctuation. And show us some of your code. How on earth should anyone help you with this tiny amount of information?

Comment: … the fiddle was lost in the Question. The OP just didn't link it right.

Comment: Now this is a valid question, voting to reopen.

Comment: Your fiddle seem to work fine. Though the jQuery version 1.4.2 is very old.

Comment: seriously i can't find any probs in your fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

Your code works and doesn't reproduce the mentioned effect/error, but it's not efficient, you can cache the objects and use `.eq()` method, you can also use the `.fadeOut()`'s callback function that is executed when animation is complete.

```
var $p = $('#container p'), i = 0;

$p.not(':first').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $p.filter(':visible').fadeOut(function(){
        $p.eq( ++i % $p.length ).fadeIn();
    });
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dAvcV/